# Iterating over dictionary(not one by one) in Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, indexing, iteration

I faced the problem:
I have dictionary like this {'a':9,'b':7,'c':12,'d':5}
Now I want to do a loop(doesn't matter why I want to do that, just example):
take first value 9 and multiply it by every other value in dict, i.e. 9*7*12*5
then I want to take second value 7 and multiply it by every value after(!) it, i.e. 7*12*5, but not including 9!
and then the same stuff with 12*5(without 9 and 7)

so the question is how to make a double loop in this case, because I can't iterate over indexes in dictionaries, it's just keys, I can't write i+1.
I may be stupid question, but I'm stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: The basic problem is that dictionaries are not ordered. You will need to define first an ordering for your keys

Answer (score 2):

If you started with some kind of ordered structure you could do the following:

```
my_list = [('a', 9), ('b', 7), ('c', 12), ('d', 5)]

def get_dict(my_list):
    my_dict = {}
    temp = 1
    for k,v in my_list[::-1]: # iterate in reverse not to multiply same numbers
                              # over and over
        temp *= v
        my_dict[k] = temp
    return my_dict
```

Result:

```
>>> get_dict(my_list)
{'a': 3780, 'c': 60, 'b': 420, 'd': 5}
```

Comment: Looks like order can come from the dict keys, so you could use `my_list = sorted(my_dict.items(), reverse=True)`

Answer (score 1):

After having ordered the keys, you can use:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
from functools import reduce

d = {'a':9,'b':7,'c':12,'d':5}

orderedKeys = sorted (d) #or whatever order you prefer
for start in range (len (orderedKeys) ):
    d [orderedKeys [start] ] = reduce (lambda x, y: x * y, (d [key] for key in orderedKeys [start:] ) )

print (d)
```

This produces the following, which is hopefully what you wanted:

```
{'b': 420, 'c': 60, 'a': 3780, 'd': 5}
```

*Why the heck has `reduce` been removed in python3?*

EDIT: Or if you prefer a dictionary comprehension you can use:

```
d = {orderedKeys [i]: reduce (lambda x, y: x * y, (d [key] for key in orderedKeys [i:] ) ) for i in range (len (orderedKeys) ) }
```

Comment: Here's what they said: `Removed reduce(). Use functools.reduce() if you really need it; however, 99 percent of the time an explicit for loop is more readable.`

Comment: hm... I thought there is a much simpler way. Anyway, thanks for quick response, that really helped! :)

Comment: The last line (the dictionary comprehension) is basically a one-liner. But as already stated you must first define an ordering over the keys.

Comment: This isn't a good use case for reduce. You turned a O(n) problem into an O(n**2)

Comment: It would surely be less expensive to just multiply the last result with the next value, that's true. The problem here isn't the use of `reduce` compared to a loop, but my poor design choice.